# comparing two integers and getting attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400058

Tags: assembly, integer, compare, mips

I have a homework problem to compare two integers and give massages based on results.

I keep getteing an Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400058 message though.

```
.data
msg1:.asciiz "Give me the first number:"
msg2:.asciiz "Give me the second number:"
msg3:.asciiz "The grater number is:"
msg4:.asciiz "The smaller number is:"
msg5:.asciiz "The two numbers are equal"
msg6:.asciiz "The two numbers are not equal"


.text
.globl main
main:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg1 
syscall


li $v0,5
syscall
move $t2,$v0


li $v0,4
la $a0,msg2
syscall


li $v0,5
syscall
move $t3,$v0


beq $t2,$t3,numbersEqual
bge $t2,$t3,number1isBigger
bge $t3,$t2,number2isBigger

numbersEqual:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg5
syscall

move $v0,$t2
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg4
syscall

move $v0,$t3
li $v0,1
syscall

nop

number1isBigger:
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg6
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg3
syscall
move $v0,$t2


li $v0,1
syscall


li $v0,4
la $a0,msg4
syscall
move $v0,$t3


li $v0,1
syscall

nop


number2isBigger:

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg6
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,msg3
syscall
move $v0,$t3


li $v0,1
syscall


li $v0,4
la $a0,msg4
syscall
move $v0,$t2


li $v0,1
syscall
nop

exit:
    li      $v0, 10              # syscall 10 terminates program 
    syscall
```

Comment: What architecture and operating system are you programming for?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. I do not see the described behavior in QtSPIM or MARS.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `nop`'s (and then falling into the next case)?  Maybe try `j exit` instead.